# How to find problematic LINQ to SQL statements?

Tags: .net, database, performance, linq-to-sql, error-handling

If a bad sql statement reaches database, how you find it in a huge system full of LINQ queries in all tiers regarding they are lazy processed?

Comment: what does "bad sql statement reaches database" mean?

Comment: I mean any sql statement that causes performance or concurrency issues. Things that can't be detected during syntax checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Profiling LINQ to SQL with the SQL Profiler](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/18/how-to-use-profiler-with-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx)
- [Profiling LINQ to SQL without using the SQL Profiler](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/05/tracing-linq-to-sql-queries-without.html) (Example: SQL Express)

Comment: We need to combine the first and second ways. Write the log and locate the query in SQL Profiler. In my opinion that is a bad feature of LINQ because it turns more difficult to fix such kind of bug.